# CPU utilization by minute for last 2-3 hours in Linux

Tags: linux, cpu-usage

I want to know the CPU utilization by minute for my Linux machine. I tried using `sar` but I got results for a 10-minute interval.  How do I get results by minute?

Comment: How many values are you looking for (1 or 60)?

Comment: I am looking one value per minute for last 2-3 hours.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with cron and some simple shell commands, which will be lightweight and not introduce too much extra loading which might skew the results.

E.G. one I just rustled up:

```
aq> crontab -l
# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR     sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name command to be executed

* * * * * uptime | sed 's/.*://' | cat - /tmp/cputime | head -180 > /tmp/cputime2 ; mv /tmp/cputime2 /tmp/cputime
```

aq> cat /tmp/cputime

```
1.28, 0.73, 0.56
0.38, 0.41, 0.45
0.38, 0.41, 0.45
0.38, 0.41, 0.45
0.38, 0.41, 0.45
0.38, 0.41, 0.45
```

This will top-post into the file and only keep the last 180 minutes = 3 hours of output.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried using `sar` but I got results for a 10-minute interval. How do I get results by minute?

`sar` reads files where scripts from the sysstat's set of tools write to. Sysstat uses cron to run `sa1` periodically. In my Kubuntu the relevant file is `/etc/cron.d/sysstat`. This line

```
5-55/10 * * * * root command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1
```

is responsible for running `debian-sa1` every 10 minutes (`debian-sa1` is a wrapper over `sa1`; if your distro is neither Debian nor its derivative, you should probably use sole `sa1` instead).

Modify this line to get what you want ([there's no need to restart cron](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10193931/10765659)). Two ways:

1. Changing the schedule. Straightforwardly run the tool each minute:

   ```
   * * * * * root command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1
   ```
2. Changing the command. `sa1` itself can iterate measurements and the syntax is `sa1 interval count`. Run the tool every ten minutes but let each invocation do 10 measurements in 60-second intervals:

   ```
   5-55/10 * * * * root command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 60 10
   ```

   (Note in this case `5-55/10` may as well be `*/10`).

The latter method seems over-complicated, yet it's useful if you want to take measurements more than once a minute. Cron does not go down to sub-minute resolutions, yet `sa1` uses seconds. Example:

```
* * * * * root command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 10 6
```

which means "every minute take 6 measurements with 10-second intervals". Here cron is responsible for the "every minute" part, then each new `sa1` process does "6 measurements with 10-second intervals".

After you set this up, it's all about `sar` invocation to get data "for last 2-3 hours" (try with `-s` and `-e` options, see `man 1 sar` for details).